# Why is my custom validation method returning an error message in array format

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my custom validation method:

```
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('postcode', 'Postcode should not be empty')
        ->add('postcode', [
            'postcode_valid'=> [
                'provider' => 'table',
                'rule' => 'validatePostcode',
                'message' => 'Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Postleitzahl ein',
            ]
        ]);
```

If some invalid data is entered in the postcode field the `errors()` method of the table will return an array like this:

```
Array
(
[address] => Array
    (
        [postcode] => Array
            (
                [postcode_valid] => Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Postleitzahl ein
            )

    )
)
```

Why is there an extra array? All the other validation error messages are only strings. Can I change my custom validation method to only return a string?

Comment: I have some doubts that this is what the output looks like, as the validator uses the rules fieldnames for the top level array keys. Is that maybe a stripped down example? If you really get a numerical indexed array, then I'd suggest that you provide a reproducible example so that someone can have a look at what exactly is going on (don't forget to mention the _exact_ CakePHP version that you are using!).

Comment: You're right @ndm, I stripped it down and I apologize for not taking more care with this question. I will update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation error was not created by the main model, but by an associated model and therefore had one more wrapping array with the model name as key.

(In my example it is a registration form. The main model is `user` and some fields of the form belong to the associated model `address`. One of those fields created the validation error).